# run java file by shell script - where the java file and shell script are in same package

Tags: java, shell

I have a snmp agent running in my machine, which will run a shell script when a snmpwalk request came to the agent with a particular OID. By

exec TestFile /bin/sh /location/of/file/testShFile.sh

Then the sh file in turns call a java file to check the connectivity to other server and returns the o/p to snmp request.

Java file is in package --> a.b.foo.test.Test.java
and sh file also resided in --> a.b.foo.test.testShFile.sh

Now how to run the java file from this shell script, as i am getting a NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: Can you paste your sh file code i mean calling java file lines

Comment: # bin/sh cd a/b/foo/test javac Test.java java Test

Comment: There is no such thing as a package for shell scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Extend your shell batch file to output or log the current setting of the classpath. Probably its not set at all.

Why don't you directly invoke the other Java method?

Comment: Because in snpm agent file i think we cant invoke .class files. If u look at the command, snmp cant recognize java

Comment: Well you could immediately spawn another thread which invokes the other method. This would free any listeners in the snmp agent. Its a standard way to handle this kind of request.

Answer (score 0):

`java -classpath /location/of/parent/of/A/directory a.b.foo.test.Test`